# SEDE query for questions asked per month (help needed)

Tags: support, data-explorer

While editing/writing a SEDE query I ran into a problem. I used the `posts` data table and used an id of 1.

Is that questions or answers? And if not what is the respective id for questions and answers or where can I find that ID information?

Comment: Related: *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677)*

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[Query for amount of upvotes per month on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341324)*

Comment: The `id` field in the `Posts` table is the Question/Answers ID#.  The field you're thinking of is `PostTypeId`. (Questions=1, Answers=2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see by clicking the 'i' by the `PostTypes` table (or by running a quick `select * from posttypes`), `Posts` with a `PostTypeID` of 1 are questions; those of 2 are answers.